# Ensuring promise fails

Tags: javascript, angular

Maybe the below works as-is but I am unsure if this is the correct implementation to prevent any possible issues at run time.

Having this:

```
  const ep = `${environment.api.baseUrl}/login`;
  return this.http.post<ILoginResponse>(ep, request).pipe(map(req => {
    this.storage.set(environment.storage_keys.token, req.access_token).then(() => {
      this.authState$.next(true);
    });
    return req;
  })).toPromise();
```

How can I make sure that the `toPromise()` will be rejected if `this.storage.set` returns an exception or fails for any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map in this case does not make sense because you're not mapping anything.
You can simply do this:

```
const ep = `${environment.api.baseUrl}/login`;
return this.http.post<ILoginResponse>(ep, request)
    .toPromise()
    .then(
        req => {
            this.storage.set(environment.storage_keys.token, req.access_token).then(
                () => this.authState$.next(true)
            );
            return req;
        }
    )
```

This will solve if `this.storage` fails.
Example:

```js
const promiseError = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => reject('err')
)

const promiseOk = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => resolve('ok')
)

promiseOk
    .then(
        req => {
            promiseError
                .then(
                    () => console.log('fa')
                )
                .catch(
                    err => console.log('err')
                )
            return req;
        }
    )
    .then(
        req => console.log(req)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the Promise constructor instead of `toPromise` to create your own for more fine-grained control:

```
const ep = `${environment.api.baseUrl}/login`;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.post<ILoginResponse>(ep, request).pipe(map(req => {
    this.storage.set(environment.storage_keys.token, req.access_token).then(() => {
      this.authState$.next(true);
      resolve(/* optionally return data here */);
    }).catch(e => reject(e));
  })).catch(e => reject(e)); // Assuming this.http.post returns a promise
})
```